# choosing between $0 and BASH_SOURCE

Tags: bash

How does one choose between `"$0"` and `"${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`

This description from [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#Bash-Variables) didn't help me much.

```
    BASH_SOURCE
    
 An array variable whose members are the source filenames where the
 corresponding shell function names in the FUNCNAME array variable are
 defined. The shell function ${FUNCNAME[$i]} is defined in the file
 ${BASH_SOURCE[$i]} and called from ${BASH_SOURCE[$i+1]}
```

Comment: `BASH_SOURCE` was added at bash-3.0-alpha. You may not have it, depending on your testing regime. I found it missing on both early Solaris and OS X. Also see [return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/468579/56041) on U&L.SE.

Comment: does anyone else think that `An array variable whose members are the source filenames where the
 corresponding shell function names in the FUNCNAME array variable are
 defined. The shell function ${FUNCNAME[$i]} is defined in the file
 ${BASH_SOURCE[$i]} and called from ${BASH_SOURCE[$i+1]}` is complete gibberish? I have no idea what that means...would be nice if someone explained what the docs/man page actually is trying to say.

Comment: The docs make more sense when I realized they were describing the bits and pieces necessary to construct a stack trace. Bash doesn't have a stack trace library itself (that I could find). Instead, I had to use FUNCNAME and BASH_SOURCE to build my own...

Answer (score 352, accepted):

<sup>Note: For a *POSIX-compliant* solution, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29835459/45375).</sup>

`${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` (or, more simply, `$BASH_SOURCE`<sup>[1]</sup>
) contains the (potentially relative) path of the containing script in *all* invocation scenarios, notably also when the script is *sourced*, which is not true for `$0`.

<sup>Furthermore, as [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) points out, `$0` can be set to an *arbitrary* value by the caller.

On the flip side, `$BASH_SOURCE` *can* be empty, if no named file is involved; e.g.:

`echo 'echo "[$BASH_SOURCE]"' | bash`</sup>

The following example illustrates this:

Script `foo`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "[$0] vs. [${BASH_SOURCE[0]}]"
```

---

```
$ bash ./foo
[./foo] vs. [./foo]

$ ./foo
[./foo] vs. [./foo]

$ . ./foo
[bash] vs. [./foo]
```

`$0` is part of the POSIX shell specification, whereas `BASH_SOURCE`, as the name suggests, is Bash-specific.

---

[1] **Optional reading: `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` vs. `$BASH_SOURCE`**:

Bash allows you to reference element `0` of an *array* variable using *scalar* notation: instead of writing `${arr[0]}`, you can write `$arr`; in other words: if you reference the variable *as if it were a scalar*, you get the element at index `0`.

Using this feature obscures the fact that `$arr` is an array, which is why popular shell-code linter [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) issues the following warning (as of this writing):

> SC2128: Expanding an array without an index only gives the first element.

On a side note: While this warning is helpful, it could be more precise, because you won't necessarily get the *first* element: It is specifically the element at index `0` that is returned, so if the first element has a higher index - which is possible in Bash - you'll get the empty string; try `a[1]='hi'; echo "$a"`.
(By contrast, `zsh`, ever the renegade, returns *all* elements as a single string, separated with the first char. stored in `$IFS`, which is a *space* by default).

You may choose to eschew this feature due to its obscurity, but it works predictably and, pragmatically speaking, you'll rarely, if ever, need to access indices *other* than `0` of array variable `${BASH_SOURCE[@]}`.

---

**Optional reading, part 2: Under what conditions does the `BASH_SOURCE` array variable actually contain *multiple* elements?**:

`BASH_SOURCE` only has multiple entries *if function calls are involved*, in which case its elements parallel the `FUNCNAME` array that contains all function names *currently on the call stack*.

That is, inside a function, `${FUNCNAME[0]}` contains the name of the executing function, and `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` contains the path of the script file in which that function is defined, `${FUNCNAME[1]}` contains the name of the function from which the currently executing function was called, if applicable, and so on.

If a given function was invoked directly from the top-level scope in the script file that defined the function at level `$i` of the call stack, `${FUNCNAME[$i+1]}` contains:

- `main` (a pseudo function name), if the script file was invoked *directly* (e.g., `./script`)
- `source` (a pseudo function name), if the script file was *sourced* (e.g. `source ./script` or `. ./script`).

Comment: so $BASH_SOURCE is more generic and works in more circumstances?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Yes, if you're using Bash, `$BASH_SOURCE` is the better choice.

Comment: @CharlieParker, please see the new bottom section I've added to the answer.

Comment: "(By contrast, zsh, ever the renegade, indeed does return the first element, irrespective of its index)." Actually, in zsh, an unsubscripted array parameter expansion becomes the whole array, not just the first item. Without shwordsplit set,`$ary` ~= `"${ary[@]}"`, `"$ary"` ~= `"${ary[*]}"`, and `$=ary` ~= `${ary[*]}` or `${ary[@]}` without the quotes.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkReed - I've updated the answer to fix the incorrect statement, but I didn't go into as much depth as your comment does, given that the original comment was just an aside.

Answer (score 58):

These scripts may help illustrate.  The outer script calls the middle script, which calls the inner script:

```
$ cat outer.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
./middle.sh
```

```
$ cat middle.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
./inner.sh
```

```
$ cat inner.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "\$0 = '$0'"
echo "\${BASH_SOURCE[0]} = '${BASH_SOURCE[0]}'"
echo "\${BASH_SOURCE[1]} = '${BASH_SOURCE[1]}'"
echo "\${BASH_SOURCE[2]} = '${BASH_SOURCE[2]}'"
```

```
$ ./outer.sh
$0 = './inner.sh'
$BASH_SOURCE[0] = './inner.sh'
$BASH_SOURCE[1] = ''
$BASH_SOURCE[2] = ''
```

However, if we change the script calls to `source` statements:

```
$ cat outer.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source ./middle.sh
```

```
$ cat middle.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source ./inner.sh
```

```
$ cat inner.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "\$0 = '$0'"
echo "\${BASH_SOURCE[0]} = '${BASH_SOURCE[0]}'"
echo "\${BASH_SOURCE[1]} = '${BASH_SOURCE[1]}'"
echo "\${BASH_SOURCE[2]} = '${BASH_SOURCE[2]}'"
```

```
$ ./outer.sh
$0 = './outer.sh'
$BASH_SOURCE[0] = './inner.sh'
$BASH_SOURCE[1] = './middle.sh'
$BASH_SOURCE[2] = './outer.sh'
```

Answer (score 28):

For portability, use `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` when it is defined, and `$0` otherwise. That gives

```
${BASH_SOURCE[0]:-$0}
```

Notably, in say zsh, the `$0` does contain correct filepath even if the script is `source`d.

Comment: It depends what you want it for. $BASH_SOURCE[-1] is probably more equivalent to $0 if you want the name of the script that is running rather than the file which has been sourced.

Comment: @TomTanner If we were considering solely bash, then your comment would be correct. But this is about compatibility with non-Bash shells. The whole point of this trick is that `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` gets evaluated to non-empty string (and becomes the result of the entire expression) in Bash, while the `$0` only gets evaluated if the shell is not Bash (and does not define `BASH_SOURCE`). In ZSH, the equivalent of `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` is `$0`.

Comment: Yes, but just pointing out, ${BASH_SOURCE[-1]} is the equivalent of $0 in bash, ksh and (bourne) sh. I've run across this particular issue recently. ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} in a "source"d file refers to the name of the sourced file, which isn't always what you want

Comment: I did not test other shells than bash and zsh, so maybe the 'compatibility maneuver' that I intend can be done in a still more portable way

Answer (score 28):

**TL;DR** I'd recommend using `${BASH_SOURCE:-$0}` as the most universal variant.

Previous answers are good but they do not mention one caveat of using `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` directly: if you invoke the script as `sh`'s argument and your `sh` is not aliased to `bash` (in my case, on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, it was linked to `dash`), it may fail with `BASH_SOURCE` variable being empty/undefined. Here's an example:

t.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "\$0:                     [$0]"
echo "\$BASH_SOURCE:           [$BASH_SOURCE]"
echo "\$BASH_SOURCE or \$0:    [${BASH_SOURCE:-$0}]"
echo "\$BASH_SOURCE[0] or \$0: [${BASH_SOURCE[0]:-$0}]"
```

(Successfully) runs:

```
$ ./t.sh
$0:                    [./t.sh]
$BASH_SOURCE:          [./t.sh]
$BASH_SOURCE or $0:    [./t.sh]
$BASH_SOURCE[0] or $0: [./t.sh]

$ source ./t.sh
$0:                    [/bin/bash]
$BASH_SOURCE:          [./t.sh]
$BASH_SOURCE or $0:    [./t.sh]
$BASH_SOURCE[0] or $0: [./t.sh]

$ bash t.sh
$0:                    [t.sh]
$BASH_SOURCE:          [t.sh]
$BASH_SOURCE or $0:    [t.sh]
$BASH_SOURCE[0] or $0: [t.sh]
```

And finally:

```
$ sh t.sh
$0:                    [t.sh]
$BASH_SOURCE:          []
$BASH_SOURCE or $0:    [t.sh]
t.sh: 6: t.sh: Bad substitution
```

### Resume

As you see, only the third variant: `${BASH_SOURCE:-$0}` - works and gives consistent result under all invocation scenarios. Note that we take advantage of [bash's feature](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) of making a reference to an unsubscripted array variable equal to the first array element.

Comment: Using the unsubscripted array is a good idea, however using a bash feature in a shell script looking for POSIX compliance seems not very wise. It implies that you'll have different behaviors when sourced depending on the executing shell,  thus it seems preferable to avoid that here and stick with `$0` in POSIX 'mode', no ?

Comment: @Zilog80 Actually, I'm not seeking for POSIX compliance, there is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29835459/45375) for it, I just offer the way to make it work under most probable (as I understand it) circumstances, not caring what shell dialect is actually hidden under `/bin/sh` (still, hoping, it'll be `bash` :)

Comment: sh t.sh get fixed now. 

bash version 5.1.16

Comment: By using `/bin/sh`, you _are_ seeking POSIX compliance.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It is the only setup which allows me to call my script from any working directory and have nested bash sources correctly resolve themselves. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I always use $0, $BASH_SOURCE can be confusing.

Adding this to top of script file to ensure calling 'return' or 'exit' correctly because 'exit' in a sourced script may go to unintended consequence as it may make terminal quit.

```
# Ensure to use exit safely later
if [[ $BASH_SOURCE != $0 ]]; then
    echo "Don't source this file, Bash it."
    return
fi
```