# Run a script in the same directory as the current script

Tags: bash, path, filepath

I have two Bash scripts in the same folder (saved somewhere by the user who downloads the entire repository):

- `script.sh` is run by the user
- `helper.sh` is required and run by `script.sh`

The two scripts should be in the same directory. I need the first script to call the second one, but there are two problems:

1. Knowing the current working directory is useless to me, because I don't know how the user is executing the first script (could be with `/usr/bin/script.sh`, with `./script.sh`, or it could be with `../Downloads/repo/scr/script.sh`)
2. The script `script.sh` will be changing to a different directory before calling `helper.sh`.

I can definitely hack together Bash that does this by storing [the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246128/617937) in a variable, but that code seems needlessly complicated for what I imagine is a very common and simple task.

Is there a standard way to *reliably* call `helper.sh` from within `script.sh`? And will work in any Bash-supported operating system?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Since `$0` holds the full path of the script that is running, you can use [`dirname`](http://ss64.com/bash/dirname.html) against it to get the path of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

script_name=$0
script_full_path=$(dirname "$0")

echo "script_name: $script_name"
echo "full path: $script_full_path"
```

so if you for example store it in `/tmp/a.sh` then you will see an output like:

```
$ /tmp/a.sh
script_name: /tmp/a.sh
full path: /tmp
```

so

> 1. Knowing the current working directory is useless to me, because I don't know how the user is executing the first script (could be with
>      `/usr/bin/script.sh`, with `./script.sh`, or it could be with
>      `../Downloads/repo/scr/script.sh`)

Using `dirname "$0"` will allow you to keep track of the original path.

> 2. The script `script.sh` will be changing to a different directory before calling `helper.sh`.

Again, since you have the path in `$0` you can `cd` back to it.

Comment: Briefly, using `$0` won't work as expected with script sourcing. For bash there is the `BASH_SOURCE` alternative.

Comment: $0 will NOT work for sub script files executed inside the original script

Comment: @AlexChe I used `${BASH_SOURCE%/*}` and it worked when executed manually but failed when started by cron. Changed it to `$(dirname "$0")` and now everything works fine.

Comment: @AndreKR, is it possible that cron uses other shell, not Bash, on your system? See this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/678410/what-shell-is-used-by-cron) for an example.

Comment: @AlexChe Good point. I didn't have a shebang in the script and the crontab shell is set to `/bin/sh` - which apparently on Ubuntu is `dash`.

Answer (score 54):

`$0` is considered [unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006457/choosing-between-0-and-bash-source) and [fragile](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028#Why_.240_is_NOT_an_option) by many devs. I have found another solution, it is safe for a chain of bash scripts and `source`.

If `a.sh` needs to execute `b.sh` (located in the same folder) using a **child** bash process:

```
#!/bin/bash
__dir="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"
bash ${__dir}/b.sh
```

If `a.sh` needs to execute `b.sh` (located in the same folder) using the **same** bash process:

```
#!/bin/bash
__dir="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"
source ${__dir}/b.sh
```

Comment: Your link points to a deleted comment. Do you have another source to support the unsafe claim? Related posts that explain about the issues with `$0`: [choosing between $0 and BASH_SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35006457/7328782), [how to get script directory in POSIX sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29832037/7328782).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Believe this is the link: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028

Comment: @CrisLuengo actually the accepted answer at least explains why `$0` is the incorrect thing to do. Cause `$0` gives the wrong location in the case the script is sourced, cause then `$0` contains the location of the script that is doing the sourcing and not the location of the script being sourced.

Comment: I used `${BASH_SOURCE%/*}` and it worked when executed manually but failed when started by cron. Changed it to `$(dirname "$0")` and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 15):

> Is there a standard way to *reliably* call `helper.sh` from within
> `script.sh`? And will work in any Bash-supported operating system?

In ***most cases***, when `helper.sh` is in the same directory as `script.sh`, you can use in `script.sh` command:

```
. ${0%/*}/helper.sh
```

*Explanation:*
`$0` stores the name of your process (in ***most cases*** it's the full path to your script).
`${parameter%word}` removes suffix pattern `word` from variable `$parameter` (in the command above it removes file name `/*` from the full path stored in variable `$0`).

If for ***some reasons*** (described in other answers) you don't want to use `$0`, you can use `$BASH_SOURCE` instead:

```
. ${BASH_SOURCE%/*}/helper.sh
```

And if you want, you can use `source` instead of `.`:

```
source ${BASH_SOURCE%/*}/helper.sh
```

As for me, it's the easiest way to achieve your goal.

Comment: I used `${BASH_SOURCE%/*}` and it worked when executed manually but failed when started by cron. Changed it to `$(dirname "$0")` and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard variable block I have in all of my scripts:

```bash
# Initialize global variables.
{
  declare SCRIPT_INVOKED_NAME="${BASH_SOURCE[${#BASH_SOURCE[@]}-1]}"
  declare SCRIPT_NAME="${SCRIPT_INVOKED_NAME##*/}"
  declare SCRIPT_INVOKED_PATH="$( dirname "${SCRIPT_INVOKED_NAME}" )"
  declare SCRIPT_PATH="$( cd "${SCRIPT_INVOKED_PATH}"; pwd )"
  declare SCRIPT_RUN_DATE="$( date )"
}
```

I then use `SCRIPT_PATH` to load other scripts in the same directory:

```bash
source "${SCRIPT_PATH}/script-helpers.inc.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$0` variable. But this won't be as simple as getting current script name:

```sh
d=${0%/*}
[ x"$d" = x"$0" ] && d=.   # portable variant, use [[ ...]] in bash freely
readonly d                 # optional, for additional safety

# ... later on
. "$d"/helper.sh
```

This works well in `set -e` case as well.

Comment: What is the `[ x"$d" = x"$0" ]` syntax please? What is the syntactical function of `x` before the arguments to the equality operator. Or in the following idiom `[  -z ${var+x} ]` ?

Comment: @vonspotz For the first question: it saves you from errors that may be caused if either `$0` or `$d` become starting with a hypen - otherwise it would be interpreted as a directive to `[ ... ]` command.

Comment: @vonspotz For the second question: `${var+x}` means "substitute with `x` if `$var` is set". Even if `$var` is empty, this would result in `x` string being substituted. But in case `$var` was not set at all, nothing will be substituted. So this is a totally different to the `[ x"$foo" = x"$bar" ]` question.