# How can I disable python 2.7 code compatibility error message in Pycharm when using wrapper around remote python 3 interpreter?

Tags: python, ssh, pycharm

I want to avoid
[these kind of messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atjZo.png) popping up, as I am not even using python 2.7. Note that the code runs fine.

I have tried the following things:

- Unchecking 'Code compatibility inspection'
- Checking 'Code compatibility inspection', but unchecking python 2.7
- Invalidate Caches/Restart
- [Editing '.idea/misc.xml': component/version from 2 to 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M80tC.png)

I am using a .sh wrapper around the python executable on the server as I want Pycharm to first source my ~/.bash_profile before using the interpreter (similar to [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686564/how-to-keep-environment-variables-for-remote-python-interpreter-with-pycharm.)).
I think that this might be the reason PyCharm doesn't recognize it as being python 3: if I point directly to the remote interpreter, the code compatibility issue dissappears.

Is there any way to keep the benefits of the wrapper and getting rid of these error messages?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, PyCharm is unable to determine Python version and uses 2.7 as a fallback.

Since 2019.3 the latest Python is used by default (3.8 at the moment), please try the [EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/) build.