# The meaning of ${BASH_SOURCE-$0}?

Tags: bash

I saw this shell script in Zookeeper `zkClear.sh`.

```
ZOOBIN="${BASH_SOURCE-$0}"
```

Can anyone tell me the meaning of this script?
Thanks.

Comment: Why has this question been closed? This is a valid question which request the meaning and subtleties about this notation.

Comment: What part you don't understand? The `${...}` or what `BASH_SOURCE` means?

Comment: ... Or the parameter expansion, or the specific reason this particular use case uses this particular parameter expansion?

Comment: BASH_SOURCE-$0      this confused me so much. Can I treat "BASH_SOURCE" here as a string? What does it mean when BASH_SOURCE "minus" $0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very subtle. While there is no significant difference between `${BASH_SOURCE-$0}` and `$BASH_SOURCE` in bash, it becomes practical when sourcing bash files in zsh.

---

There are two aspects here:

1. The meaning of the array `BASH_SOURCE` and it's relation to `$0`: This is well explained in [choosing between $0 and BASH_SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006457/choosing-between-0-and-bash-source). However, the value of `BASH_SOURCE` is only defined within the context of bash. Other shells have no knowledge of this array.
2. The parameter expansion `${var-string}`: when browsing the man pages of `bash` or any POSIX related shell such as sh, ksh and even zsh, you can find that `${var-string}` resolves in `string` if the variable `var` does not exist.

So imagine now the following scripts:

```
$ cat src.bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "$0, ${BASH_SOURCE}, ${BASH_SOURCE-$0}"
$ cat exe.bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source ./src.bash
$ cat exe.zsh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
source ./src.bash
```

When you execute these scripts in bash directly, you get the following results:

```
$ echo "$0, ${BASH_SOURCE}, ${BASH_SOURCE-$0}"
bash, , bash
$ source src.bash
bash, src.bash, src.bash
$ ./exe.bash
./exe.bash, ./src.bash, ./src.bash
```

This clearly shows that there is no significant difference between `$BASH_SOURCE` and `${BASH_SOURCE-$0}`. Only when executed directly from the bash terminal as `BASH_SOURCE` does not exist and is accordingly replaced.

From zsh, the story is different.

```
$ echo "$0, ${BASH_SOURCE}, ${BASH_SOURCE-$0}"
-zsh, , -zsh
$ source src.bash
src.bash, , src.bash
$ ./exe.zsh
./src.bash, , ./src.bash
```

Even though zsh has no knowledge of the variable `BASH_SOURCE`, it also slightly changes the behaviour of `$0`. For bash, `$0` is always the name of the current executed script while in zsh it is the name of the current executed **or** sourced script. In the above, you clearly see the difference between `$BASH_SOURCE` and `${BASH_SOURCE-$0}`. The latter always returns the value of the current executed or sourced file.

**In conclusion**, one could say that `${BASH_SOURCE-$0}` is a simple hack to get the path of the sourced file, independently of the shell the script is sourced from (zsh vs bash). Whether this is used for this reason in the original script is not certain, however it is likely that the author of the script had something like this in mind or is used to write source files that can be used both in zsh and bash.

Comment: Thanks very much. Now I understand how this script works.

Answer (score 1):

From [bash parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> [...] Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset. Put another way, if the colon is included, the operator tests for both parameter’s existence and that its value is not null; if the colon is omitted, the operator tests only for existence.
>
> ```
> ${parameter:-word}
> ```
>
> If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

So:

> ```
> ZOOBIN="${BASH_SOURCE-$0}"
> ```

So we have:

| BASH_SOURCE | ZOOBIN= |
| --- | --- |
| unset | $0 |
| set, not empty | $BASH_SOURCE |
| null (set&empty) | $BASH_SOURCE, which is null, so ZOOBIN will also be null |

`null` means "set and empty", like `var=''` or just `var=`.

Prefer to use `:-` so that if variable is empty, then use alternative word. As I doubt `BASH_SOURCE` will ever be set but empty, if it's set it's going to have some path, this code is just fine.

And `BASH_SOURCE` is explained in [bash variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html).

> The meaning of ${BASH_SOURCE-$0}?

The *meaning* strongly depends on context. The meaning could be that if the file is sourced or running with `bash`, then prefer to use `BASH_SOURCE` variable. But if it is not sourced and not running under bash, ex running in `ash`, then use `$0`. The name `ZOOBIN` suggest some path to binary and `ZOO` is probably some application prefix.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This explanation of parameter expansion is new knowledge to me.

Answer (score 0):

${BASH_SOURCE[0]} contains the path of the containing script in all invocation scenarios. So when you source this variable, you'll get the path of the bash script.

So, in your case you print out the first element you retrieve when you call it from the environment as ${BASH_SOURCE}, which prints out "bash"(in my environment)

Read more here in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35006505/12592220

This link also explains it detail:https://www.systutorials.com/how-to-get-bash-scripts-own-path/