# How to only concatenate files with same identifier using bash script?

Tags: bash, concatenation

I have a directory with files, some have the same ID, which is given in the first part of the file name before the first underscore (always). e.g.:

```
S100_R1.txt
S100_R2.txt
S111_1_R1.txt
S111_R1.txt
S111_R2.txt
S333_R1.txt
```

I want to concatenate those identical IDs (and if possible placing the original files in another `dir`, e.g. output:

```
original files (folder)
S100_merged.txt
S111_merged.txt
S333_R1.txt
```

Small note: I imaging that perhaps a solution would be to place all files which will be processed by the code in a new directory and than in a second step move the files with the appended "merged" back to the original `dir` or something like this...

I am **extremely** new to bash scripting, so I really can't produce this code. I am use to R language and I can think how it should be but can't write it.

My pitiful attempt is  something like this:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' id; do
    cat *"$id" > "./${id%.txt}_grouped.txt"
done < <(printf '%s\0' *.txt | cut -zd_ -f1- | sort -uz)
```

or this:

```
for ((k=100;k<400;k=k+1)); 
do
IDList= echo "S${k}_S*.txt" | awk -F'[_.]' '{$1}'
while [ IDList${k} == IDList${k+n} ]; do
        cat IDList${k}_S*.txt IDList${k+n}_S*.txt S${k}_S*.txt S${k}_S*.txt >cat/S${k}_merged.txt &; 
  done
```

Sometimes there are only one version of the file (e.g. S333_R1.txt) sometime two (S100*), three (S111*) or more of the same.

I am prepared for harsh critique for this question because I am so far from a solution, but if someone would be willing to help me out I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Can the output `S333_R1.txt` file be named `S333_merged.txt`?

Comment: yeah that shouldn't be a big problem... but preferable not. But I'll take it, if that's part of a solution you have :)

Comment: `printf '%s\0' *.txt` Does your files really have newlines in filenames? If so, you'll better off with python.

Comment: Honestly (and I am sorry) I don't fully understand the command  - I have copy-pasted it from other online code examples and tried to "modulate" it into my situation. "New lines in file name": No, that is not something I have. What would that even look like.....

Comment: `touch something$'\n'something_after_newline ; ls` See for yourself :p

Comment: @Mathilde : For a given ID, you can group the files with this id by `cat "$id"_*.txt >"$di"_merged.txt`.

Comment: @Mathilde : I would separtae the problem into two different subproblems: (1) Find all those IDs which are required for the combining process (`S100` and `S111` in your example). (2) Group those files for a given ID. Write separate shell scripts for each subproblem (so that you can debug them separately). Finally write a master script which peruses the scripts (1) and (2) to achieve the overall desired effect.

Comment: @user1934428 Thank you for your comments, regarding your first suggestion, as I understand I would need to know the ID and write it e.g. cat "$S100"_*.txt > "$S100"_merged.txt or? That would not be so feasible for a case with many IDs.

Comment: @Mathilde : That's why you need the script I refered to as '(1)'. A script which calculates all possible IDs and from them  picks only those for which there are at least 2 files starting with the same ID. This is also the way we would do it manually. Hence, you need a script `get_ids` which produces on stdout a list of the ids to safe, and then another one called merge_ids, and finally you combine those.

Comment: I see. My skills are so damn limited here, it is very frustrating, but hopefully I will get better fast! Would love to be good (or just moderate okay) at this stuff. As always, I am GRATEFUL for the feedback on this forum!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for id in $(ls | grep -Po '^[^_]+' | uniq) ; do
    if [ $(ls ${id}_*.txt 2> /dev/null | wc -l) -gt 1 ] ; then
        cat ${id}_*.txt > _${id}_merged.txt
        mv ${id}_*.txt folder
    fi
done

for f in _*_merged.txt ; do
    mv ${f} ${f:1}
done
```

Comment: @Abelisto : This would produce for the example input provided by the OP also a file `S333_merged.txt`, which is not desired.

Comment: @Mathilde Fixed wrongly moving `*_merged.txt` files to the `folder`

Comment: I do get a S333_merged in both the long and short version of this script. in addition I get something called 'folder' but it isn't a folder (perhaps a Windows problem) and no files have moved folders. Hope that was okay clear.

Comment: `folder` here is a `dir` from your question: "placing the original files in another `dir`" And it should be created before running this script.

Comment: ah I see! now the files are moved there. one issue is though that I still get the S333_merged file and also a txt file called "folder_merged", Actually I get for all files in the folder also bash files, which is not optimal. Can it be written to only consider txt files?

Comment: @Mathilde You could to use `ls ${id}_*.txt 2> /dev/null | wc -l` to count files and do nothing if there is only one file with specified `id`. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

A plain bash loop with preprocessing:

```
# first get the list of files
find . -type f |
# then extract the prefix
sed 's@./\([^_]*\)_@\1\t&@' |
# then in a loop merge the files
while IFS=$'\t' read prefix file; do
     cat "$file" >> "${prefix}_merged.txt"
done
```

That script is iterative - one file at a time. To detect if there is one file of specific prefix, we have to look at all files at a time. So first an `awk` script to join list of filenames with common prefix:

```
find . -type f |    # maybe `sort |` ?
# join filenames with common prefix
awk '{ 
      f=$0;                            # remember the file path
      gsub(/.*\//,"");gsub(/_.*/,"");  # extract prefix from filepath and store it in $0
      a[$0]=a[$0]" "f                  # Join path with leading space in associative array indexed with prefix
    }
    # Output prefix and filanames separated by spaces.
    # TBH a tab would be a better separator..
    END{for (i in a) print i a[i]}
' |
# Read input separated by spaces into a bash array
while IFS=' ' read -ra files; do
     #first array element is the prefix
    prefix=${files[0]}
    unset files[0]
    # rest is the files
    case "${#files[@]}" in
    0) echo super error; ;;
    # one file - preserve the filename
    1) cat "${files[@]}" > "$outdir"/"${files[1]}"; ;;
    # more files - do a _merged.txt suffix
    *) cat "${files[@]}" > "$outdir"/"${prefix}_merged.txt"; ;;
    esac
done
```

[Tested on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/ConventionalQuintessentialBrowser#main.sh).

---

> ```
> IDList= echo "S${k}_S*.txt"
> ```

Executes the command `echo` with the environment variable `IDList` exported and set to empty with one argument equal to `S<insert value of k here>_S*.txt`.

Filename expansion (ie. `*` -> list of files) is not executed inside `"` double quotes.

To assign a result of execution into a variable, use command substitution `var=$( something seomthing | seomthing )`

> IDList${k+n}_S*.txt

The `${var+pattern}` is a variable expansion that **does not** add two variables together. It uses `pattern` when `var` is set and does nothing when `var` is unset. See [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66024681/the-meaning-of-bash-source-0/66025499#66025499) on `${var-pattern}`, but it's similar.

To add two numbers use arithemtic expansion `$((k + n))`.

> ```
> awk -F'[_.]' '{$1}'
> ```

`$1` is just invalid here. To print a line, print it `{print %1}`.

Remember to check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net

Comment: 1st: THANK YOU! looking at this I think, I would have never managed. 2nd: Copying this into a file and running it I get some errors in Line 11 ( $'\r': command not found
), and two errors in line 18 (syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''  and  `    case "${#files[@]}" in). I am running Windows using Cygwin terminal (but it is only for practice, the command will in the end be running on a Linux PC).

Comment: Your file has dos line endings - you saved it wrongly in your editor. Remove dos line endings. Research `dos2unix` and such.

Comment: I really want to thank you KamilCuk for your effort and explanations! Unfortunately I can't get it to work. When I convert it to Unix nothing happen when I run it. The same is the case with @Raman Sailopals solution. But Abelisto's code I can run and it works

Answer (score 2):

```
while read $fil;
do
  if [[ "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name $line"_*.txt" | wc -l)" -gt "1" ]]
  then
      cat $line_*.txt >> "$line_merged.txt"
  fi 
done <<< "$(for i in *_*.txt;do echo $i;done | awk -F_ '{ print $1 }')"
```

Search for files with *_*.txt and run the output into awk, printing the strings before "_". Run this through a while loop. Check if the number of files for each prefix pattern is greater than 1 using find and if it is, cat the files with that prefix pattern into a  merged file.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! - See my comment to KamilCuks post, unfortunately I cannot get your script to work, but I think it has to do with Windows vs. Linux.

Answer (score 2):

A pure `bash` way below. It uses only `glob`s (no need for external commands like `ls` or `find` for this question) to enumerate filenames and an associative array (which is supported by `bash` since the version 4.0) in order to compute frequencies of ids. Parsing `ls` output to list files is questionable in `bash`. You may consider reading [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

```
#!/bin/bash

backupdir=original_files # The directory to move the original files
declare -A count # Associative array to hold id counts

# If it is assumed that the backup directory exists prior to call, then
# drop the line below
mkdir "$backupdir" || exit

for file in [^_]*_*; do ((++count[${file%%_*}])); done
for id in "${!count[@]}"; do
    if ((count[$id] > 1)); then
        mv "$id"_* "$backupdir"
        cat "$backupdir/$id"_* > "$id"_merged.txt
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much - unfortunately I cannot get it to work, but I am facing some stupid errors which I believe have to do with running on Windows. I will test all the suggested codes on Linux ASAP. thank you all!

Comment: @Mathilde Do you run the `bash` on Windows?

Comment: yes-ish. My PC is a Windows machine.The script I am trying to write will however in the end run in a Linux environment. But because I need to LEARN so much, it is more feasible for me to sit at my own desk and practice so to speak... I thought running it in a Cygwin terminal would make it work, but yeah no, I am running into trouble. Truth be told seeing all these great answers, I realized that my skills limitations in this are bigger than I thought. So I have actually involved a colleague who is very good at this stuff and has agreed to help me. I hope it doesn't feel like I wasted your time.