# Apache Doris：Short files in the library directory

Tags: database, bigdata, open-source, data-warehouse, olap

I am using build.sh to build Doris but failed. It says:
lib/doris_be': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

The [build.sh](https://github.com/apache/doris/blob/master/build.sh) script seems to search for the be library from Apache doris in the
`${ROOT}/output/be/lib/doris_be`
directory, where ${ROOT} is taken from the [BASH_SOURCE variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35006505/151759). My assumption is that you started the script not from the root directory of the doris source code, and therefore the build script looks in the wrong directory for the be library. Can you check?